# c# delete line from textbox, and remove blank line

Tags: c#, string, file, windows-forms-designer

I have a textbox that holds file content. I have a button that when it is pressed, it deletes a line based on a string. Here is the code:

```
    private void deleteModuleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String newText = String.Empty;
        List<String> lines = fileContentTextBox.Text.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        lines.RemoveAll(str => str.Contains(deleteModuleComboBox.Text));
        lines.ForEach(str => newText += str + Environment.NewLine);
        fileContentTextBox.Text = newText;
    }
```

However, when a line is deleted it leaves a blank line at the bottom of the text box. The issue with this, is that when the file is saved. It cannot be read again because of the extra empty line. I get this error when I try to open a file that has been saved after it had a line deleted: "Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array". When I read the file, I take each line as string, and then split that line using "(',')".

Is there a way to change the code so that it takes "newText", and adds new lines, but not for last string? Or some other way, just so that there is no blank line at the end.

Thanks

EDIT: I got it working (Thanks L.B)

updated and working code:

```
    private void deleteModuleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String newText = String.Empty;
        List<String> lines = fileContentTextBox.Text.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        lines.RemoveAll(str => str.Contains(deleteModuleComboBox.Text));
        newText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
        fileContentTextBox.Text = newText;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `fileContentTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
lines.ForEach(str => newText += str + Environment.NewLine);
```

with

```
newText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine , lines);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I also worked for me when I added 
`newText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine , lines);`
Right after 
`lines.ForEach(str => newText += str + Environment.NewLine);`
But I will just replace it, thanks :)

Comment: @Dr4ken It works because `string.Join` code overrides your previous code by assigning a new value to *newText*